# Does libc show international error messages?

Tags: c, gcc, error-handling, libc

According to ISO C and POSIX error messages returned by [strerror()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strerror.html) family should be locale specific. While in my example (Mac OS X 10.10.5 / clang / c11) they are not. I checked several platforms and all of them behave in the same way.

I have checked locales by `locale -a`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <locale.h>

#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, "he_IL.UTF-8");

    errno = 0;
    // Generate unique filename.
    FILE *file = fopen(tmpnam((char[L_tmpnam]){0}), "rb");

    if (file) {
        // Do something useful. 
        fclose(file);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error message : %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Show:

```
Error message : No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a *requirement* in the Standard that error messages have translations for nonstandard locales. Further, [this manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) says that the error message string is selected (emphasis mine):

> *possibly* using the **LC_MESSAGES** part of the current locale to
>   select the appropriate language.

That said, I notice that I can change the locale to `fr_FR.UTF-8` on my system, generating the following error message for your code:

```
Error message : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

If you want error messages in Hebrew, you may have to code for them by hand. Keep in mind that many feel that error messages should not be translated; [here is a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506959/is-it-right-to-translate-error-messages) with a discussion of this topic.

Comment: I tried several locales including yours but no one works. What is your system? I checked a few online compilers and no one shows localised output.

Comment: I am using Linux Mint. You can try any of the locales shown by `locale -a`.  You may need to install a new locale; on Mint I can go into the Software Manager to install language-packs. `language-pack-fr-base` contains several French locales, `fr_FR.utf-8` among them. I also tried a German locale (`de_DE.utf-8`) that worked and gave German error messages. But I installed `language-pack-he-base` for the `he_IL.utf-8` locale (which I can see with `locale -a`), and, as you found, my error messages were stlll in English.